# Display each object in NSArray for 2 seconds

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have the following problem: I have an `NSArray` that contains 5 objects. I want to display each item for 2 seconds using `NSTimer`, and release the timer after displaying the last item in the array.

```
Country = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Aus",@"India",@"Pak",@"China",@"Japan", nil];

cntcount = [Country count];
NSLog(@"concount=%i", cntcount);

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(startTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

But I'm not getting another step. What should I do in the `starttime()` function? Please help!

```
//
//  AppViewController.m
//  NSTimerExample
//

#import "AppViewController.h"

@interface AppViewController ()

@end

@implementation AppViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    Country = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  @"Aus", @"India", @"Pak", @"China", @"Japan", nil];

    tempValue = 0; 
    NSTimer *popupTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                                           target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(startTime:)
                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:YES];
    NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runner addTimer:popupTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}

- (void)startTime:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    int cntcount = [Country count];
    if(tempValue < cntcount) {

        NSString *objectName = [Country objectAtIndex:tempValue];
        NSLog(@"objectName=%@", objectName);

        tempValue++;
    } else {
        [theTimer invalidate];
        theTimer = nil;
        // or you can reset tempValue to 0.

    }
}
```

After displaying the last item I want to release timer as it is no longer needed, but I'm getting and `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception.

Comment: what does your `startTime` method look like?

Comment: my startTime fuction will display each coutry name after 2.0 second and if control reaches last object stop the timer function call

Comment: Why you need to release NSTimer as you need it for continuous work.

Comment: after displaying last object name i want to release nstimer

Comment: @Sandeep Do You want to restart timer after release ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this,

In `.h`

```
int tempValue;
```

In `.m`

```
tempValue=0;     
NSTimer *popupTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(startTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];;
NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runner addTimer:popupTimer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

In timer action method:

```
-(void)startTime:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
    if(tempValue< Country.count) {

         // Display array object eg: label.text=[Country objectAtIndex:tempValue];

         tempValue++;
    } else {
        [theTimer invalidate];
        theTimer=nil;
        // or you can reset the tempValue into 0.

    }
}
```

Comment: if you use `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` the timer is already scheduled on the current run loop in the default mode. No need to add it to the run loop again.

Comment: what you did inside the if loop??? also check whether Country array contains objects inside the timer method.

Comment: @Sandeep i have copied your code and pasted into my application and checked. Its working fine for me....

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "AppViewController.h"

@interface AppViewController ()

@end

@implementation AppViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    Country=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Aus",@"India",@"Pak",@"China",@"Japan", nil];
    tempValue=0; 
    NSTimer *popupTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(startTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];;
    NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runner addTimer:popupTimer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}

- (void)startTime:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
    if(tempValue< Country.count) {

        NSString *objectname=[Country objectAtIndex:tempValue];
        NSLog(@"objectname is %@",objectname);       
        tempValue++;
    } else {
        [theTimer invalidate];
        theTimer=nil;
        // or you can reset the tempValue into 0.

    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

thanks to Tony and this code is working properly